# MongoDB only stores 61246 documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm quite new to MongoDB and have some problems to get a bunch of documents inserted into my collection via NodeJs.

I have a list of files (all below 100kb) to be inserted into the same collection. I use the following code with:

```
var files = walkFolder(base);
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/enron';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) { throw err;}
    var collection = db.collection('emails');
    async.each(files, function(item, callback){
            var document = readEmail(item);
            collection.insert(document, function(err, result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    callback(err);
            });
    });
});
```

`walkFolder()` creates a list of files and `readEmail()` parses a single file into a JSON object (just some properties, no embedded documents or something)

I can execute my program and it happly runs very long. But always at exactly 61246 documents in the collection (checked via `> db.emails.find().count()`) the count doesn't increase anymore.

Any idea why this is happening or how to track it down?
Some versions: MacOS 10.9.5, NodeJs 0.10.31, MongoDB driver 1.4.19, MongoDB 2.6.5

Comment: While this is basically solved by putting a "limit" on the number of concurrent inserts being queued, may I suggest that `walkFolder()` is still an issue here since it's clearly reading in a large array. You might want to consider implementing that as a [node stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) interface to reduce memory and do the "throttling" there. The [Bulk API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) for MongoDB can significantly speed things up as well, by writing your inserts in batches. Meaning less network traffic to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async.each` applies your iterator function to each `files` element in parallel.  If `files` is large, you can exhaust various resources by trying to do it all at once.  Instead, use [`async.eachLimit`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachlimitarr-limit-iterator-callback) to only process N number of elements at a time.

For example, to limit the processing to no more than 10 files in progress at any one time, replace your `async.each` call with:

```
async.eachLimit(files, 10, function(item, callback){ ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. In the meantime i was playing around with other stuff and tried `eachSeries` - which makes it absolutely serial but solves also the problem of hammering the resources. Thanks